# Concept of "UpdateSourceTrigger" Property, How to use it in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a TextBlock, binded with an Object and when i update property of object its not refleting on UI, Why ?

Code:

### In Windows1.xaml

```
<TextBlock Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Height="20" Margin="12,23,166,218" />
```

### and In Windows.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    Employee obj ;
    public Window1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        obj = new Employee();
        obj.Name = "First";
        txtName.DataContext = obj;
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        obj.Name = "changed";            
    }
}
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        set 
        {
            this._name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(Name);
        }
        get { return this._name; }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {

            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        }

    }        
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
OnPropertyChanged(Name);
```

should be:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Name");
```

otherwise if the name is set to "Kent", you're raising a property changed event saying that the "Kent" property has changed, which obviously doesn't exist.

As for `UpdateSourceTrigger`, that only applies to the source. The property you've bound is the target, not the source. And it doesn't make sense for a `TextBlock` to update its source, because there's no way for the user to modify the `TextBlock` text. A `TextBox`, on the other hand, would make sense. In that case, `UpdateSourceTrigger` determines the point at which the text in the `TextBox` is pushed back to the source property (e.g. as the user types each character, or when they move away from the `TextBox`).

Comment: thanks for your answer, now its working. I want to know if in my scenario, i replace "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" with "UpdateSourceTrigger=Default" then still its working why? i search on net but could not get the valuable answer (i searched on net PropertyChanged vs Default).

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger will only have an effect for bindings with a `Mode` of `TwoWay` or `OneWayToSource`. Such a binding wouldn't make sense for `TextBlock.Text` and attempting to create one will result in an exception. That's because - like I said - it doesn't make sense since the user cannot change the text of a `TextBlock`.

Comment: Hi Kent is it possible to update to source conditionally I.e. only if a particular check box is checked?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the name of the property as string, instead of the property value, like so:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

UpdateSourceTrigger is for binding with the source property i.e normal .net property so to it requires to set on options like property change with mode twoway for dynamic change ex.text of textbox being change and the which updtaes a label to change. Where as if you want the change event to fire at the end i.e lost focus or click use explicit option with updatesourcetrigger.

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to write your answer a bit more clearly? ;)